# PHP personalized connect.php not working

Tags: php

I am having issues making a new system for my website. I am working on a new connect.php and approved.php (for something else)
and I cannot seem to get it to work. Here is the approved.php

**approved.php**

```
<?php
    include_once "connect.php";
    include_once "strings.php";
    connect($conn[0][0], $conn[1][2], $conn[2][2], $conn[3][0]);

    //echo $newConn;

    mysqli_query($newConn, "SELECT * FROM `loginsystem`") or die("Could not connect");
?>
```

Here is the **connect.php**

```
<?php
    function connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname)
    {
        include "strings.php"; 
        if ($servername == $conn[0][0] && $username == $conn[1][0] && $password == $conn[2][0] && $dbname == $conn[3][0] || 
        $servername == $conn[0][0] && $username == $conn[1][1] && $password == $conn[2][1] && $dbname == $conn[3][0] || 
        $servername == $conn[0][0] && $username == $conn[1][2] && $password == $conn[2][2] && $dbname == $conn[3][0])
        {
            $newConn;
            if ($newConn = mysqli_connect($conn[0][0], $conn[1][0], $conn[2][0], $conn[3][0])
            || $newConn = mysqli_connect($conn[0][0], $conn[1][1], $conn[2][1], $conn[3][0])
            || $newConn = mysqli_connect($conn[0][0], $conn[1][2], $conn[2][2], $conn[3][0]))
            {
                echo $processMsg;
            }
            else 
            {
                echo $errorMsg;
                die();
            }
            return $newConn;
        }
        else if ($servername == $conn[0][0] && $username == $conn[1][0] && $password == $conn[2][0] && $dbname == $conn[3][1] || 
        $servername == $conn[0][0] && $username == $conn[1][1] && $password == $conn[2][1] && $dbname == $conn[3][1] ||
        $servername == $conn[0][0] && $username == $conn[1][2] && $password == $conn[2][2] && $dbname == $conn[3][1])
        {
            if ($newConn = mysqli_connect($conn[0][0], $conn[1][0], $conn[2][0], $conn[3][1])
            || $newConn = mysqli_connect($conn[0][0], $conn[1][1], $conn[2][1], $conn[3][1])
            || $newConn = mysqli_connect($conn[0][0], $conn[1][2], $conn[2][2], $conn[3][1]))
            {
                echo $processMsg;
            }
            else 
            {
                echo $errorMsg;
                die();
            }
            return $newConn;
            }
        else 
        {
            die("Something went wrong with our systems");
        }
    }
?>
```

And finally **strings.php** *With sensitive information taken out*

```
<?php
    //Information taken out for stack overflow question - not everything is here
    include_once("connect.php");
    $tablesChromeAds = ["food", "software", "hardware", "home", "outdoor", "indooract", "services", "other"];
    $conn = array(array($server) /*both our servers go under localhost*/, array($admin, $admin1, $localAdmin), array($adminPass, $admin1Pass, $localAdminPass), array($dbGeneralDB, $dbBrowserExtensions));
    $newConn;
    $errorMsg = "<script type='text/javascript'>Notification.requestPermission().then(function(result) {console.log(result);});var notification = new Notification('Smart Lead Advertisement Error', {icon: '$logo',body: 'Cannot connect to database'});</script>";
    $processMsg = "<script type='text/javascript'>Notification.requestPermission().then(function(e) {console.log(e);});var notification = new Notification('Smart Lead Advertisement', {icon: '$logo',body: 'Processing request...'});</script>";

    //Get the value for the presale license's from the mysql database to be stored within a variable which can be later accessed from any file 

    $num = 50;
?>
```

Now everything as far I know is included correctly. No errors happen until I try to connect. I havent had this 
problem before. The errors are as shown below

```
Notice: Undefined variable: newConn in C:\xampp\htdocs\smartlead\php\approved.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined variable: newConn in C:\xampp\htdocs\smartlead\php\approved.php on line 8

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\smartlead\php\approved.php on line 8
```

So I know one thing that the newConn variable is not being returned properly. But why? And how can I fix this?

Comment: `$newConn = connect(/* arguments */);`

Comment: Can you please clarify?

Comment: You need to assign the return value to a variable. Preceed `connect($conn[0][0], $conn[1][2], $conn[2][2], $conn[3][0]);`  with `$newConn =`.

Comment: In strings.php I put $newConn; but it wont return it.

Comment: It is returning it into the air per your current code.

Comment: I see. How can I fix this? @chris85

Comment: I already stated how. Assign the return to a variable where you make the function call.

Comment: I do not understand. Can you post an example or a JSFiddle in the answers?

Comment: this is now a classic case of variable scope and/or your query failed.

Comment: Query is okay. Tested with normal procedure. How can I fix the variable scope?

Answer (score 2):

As commented by **u_mulder**

```
$newConn =  connect($conn[0][0], $conn[1][2], $conn[2][2], $conn[3][0]);

    //echo $newConn;

    mysqli_query($newConn, "SELECT * FROM `loginsystem`") or die("Could not connect");
```

It seams that your `connection` is not established try to use echo  `mysqli_connect_error();` function

```
connect.php
<?php

function connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) {
    include "strings.php";
    if ($servername == $conn[0][0] && $username == $conn[1][0] && $password == $conn[2][0] && $dbname == $conn[3][0] ||
            $servername == $conn[0][0] && $username == $conn[1][1] && $password == $conn[2][1] && $dbname == $conn[3][0] ||
            $servername == $conn[0][0] && $username == $conn[1][2] && $password == $conn[2][2] && $dbname == $conn[3][0]) {
        $newConn;
        if ($newConn = mysqli_connect($conn[0][0], $conn[1][0], $conn[2][0], $conn[3][0]) || $newConn = mysqli_connect($conn[0][0], $conn[1][1], $conn[2][1], $conn[3][0]) || $newConn = mysqli_connect($conn[0][0], $conn[1][2], $conn[2][2], $conn[3][0])) {
            echo $processMsg;
        } else {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            echo $errorMsg;
            die();
        }
        return $newConn;
    } else if ($servername == $conn[0][0] && $username == $conn[1][0] && $password == $conn[2][0] && $dbname == $conn[3][1] ||
            $servername == $conn[0][0] && $username == $conn[1][1] && $password == $conn[2][1] && $dbname == $conn[3][1] ||
            $servername == $conn[0][0] && $username == $conn[1][2] && $password == $conn[2][2] && $dbname == $conn[3][1]) {
        if ($newConn = mysqli_connect($conn[0][0], $conn[1][0], $conn[2][0], $conn[3][1]) || $newConn = mysqli_connect($conn[0][0], $conn[1][1], $conn[2][1], $conn[3][1]) || $newConn = mysqli_connect($conn[0][0], $conn[1][2], $conn[2][2], $conn[3][1])) {
            echo $processMsg;
        } else {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            echo $errorMsg;
            die();
        }
        return $newConn;
    } else {
        die("Something went wrong with our systems");
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Now it gives the error <strong>mysqli_query(); expects paramter 1 to be mysqli. Boolean given.</strong> why is this?

Comment: No errors with connect.php only when I try to put that connection to use.

Comment: As stated in the below answer the mysqli object is not being returned. The connection is fine cause I see processing. But the returned value is bool(true) not mysqli object. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how the assignment from a function works in PHP.

```
function test() {
     $moose = 'Wow';
     return $moose;
}
test();
echo 'empty->' . $moose . "<-empty"; //undefined;
$moose = test();
echo $moose;
```

Note on the first function call `test()` we do nothing with the returned value so it is just lost. All variables are relative to their function as well. You could call the variable `$cattle` in the function then `$moose` in the script and all `$moose` references would be fine.

Demo: https://eval.in/611062

Comment: Yes, what don't you get? Look at `test();` vs. `$moose = test();`. The `return` sends back `'Wow'`, not `$moose`. If you did `echo test();` you would get `Wow` displayed on the screen.

Comment: I changed it it doesnt give errors when I put $newConn = connect(/*params*/); but it does not run. Says it requires mysqli and I provided a boolean. It gives no more information and I used mysqli_connection_error and mysqli_error

Comment: So basically the connection is made. I see the processing message. But the query wont work as I seem to have trouble passing connect into the function

Comment: Its exactly when I try to make a query such as

Comment: $newConn = connect(/*info*/);

Comment: What does `$newConn` output as if you `var_dump` it?

Comment: Sorry phone is stupid and finally try to put the newConn into a query mysqli_query($newConn, "SELECT * FROM `loginsystem`); it gives an error paramter 1 requires mysqli boolean given

Comment: It gives bool(true)

Comment: That should be a mysqli object. Your function isn't returning what it should be.

Comment: Go through your function and see which return you are sending then trace back to which connection is being used and figure out why it isn't the object.

Comment: I dont see any issues. What do you think is wrong with the function?

Comment: It is not returning the object.

Comment: What do you think I should do to return it?

Comment: Debug **why** it is sending boolean and not the object.

Comment: I dont know **how** to debug it. Ive never had this issue before.

Comment: I did some debugging and it gives an error saying.... Cannot use object of type mysqli as array